# Is there a fan maintained list of god-machine chronicles virtues and vices?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, chronicles-of-darkness-2e, online-resources, virtues-and-vices

GMC opens the door for a much wider selection of virtues and vices the new World of Darkness. The rules update moves away from cardinal sins and virtues, the book then lists a handful of each.

I'm confident I've seen a longer list compiled somewhere,  but my Google-fu is weak.

Can someone help be find an external resource for the new style virtues and vices?

Comment: Are you referring to this: http://cofab.mechanipus.com/wiki/Vices_and_Virtues

Comment: @ahriman no but it's a good resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best resource I know for a fan-maintained list is [NWoD portal at thesubnet.com](http://thesubnet.com/portal/wod2/wod2.0/). For the Virtues and Vices in the GMC chronicles, they are listed in the character Creation tab under the Mortal (Adult) [GMC] directory. As of the time of this posting, there is an error for the Virtues location in that directory (it is also listed under Vices), but the page loads correctly.

The site is an excellent resource, as the webmistress has rather extensively compiled information from most of the books and it is well-organized. It cannot replace the books, but it is a much faster codex to find the information you need.

If you would like the direct links, here are [Virtues](http://thesubnet.com/portal/wod2/wod2.0/CreationVirGMC.html) and [Vices](http://thesubnet.com/portal/wod2/wod2.0/CreationViceGMC.html)

EDIT: For children in the nWoD, White Wolf created Assets and Faults, but they are similar to the Vices and Virtues and thus not particularly helpful in this case. However [this discussion](http://shadownessence.se/forum/topic/10940-alternative-virtues-and-vices/) brings up some good points on the material to consider, as well as a few alternate Virtues.

Comment: They seem to only be lists of the ones printed in the book.

Comment: I don't think they have released any others in official materials. There might be fan-created material that you remember, however. There were also Assets and Faults, but those were just an equivalent mechanic for the children in the setting. In my search I couldn't find a list of fan-made content, but I will edit in some more information.